# How to use the same Cocos2d image (single .png) in SpriteKit Texture Atlas (to multiple .png)

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a SINGLE .png (generated from texturepacker) that i used in cocos2d to animate a button.  Now, I am migrating to SpriteKit (have to) and in using texture atlas it has to be MULTIPLE split files.  I tried to split it thru Shoebox but I can't get the right sequence. How do i do thesame animation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you are most likely looking for something like this.

```
SKTexture *fullTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"single.png"];

float widthPercent = 1.0f/(float)columns;
float heightPercent = 1.0f/(float)rows;

NSMutableArray *textureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{

    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(j*widthPercent, i*heightPercent, widthPercent, heightPercent) inTexture:fullTexture];

        [textureArray addObject:texture];
    }
}

SKAction *animate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textureArray timePerFrame:.2];
SKAction *repeatAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animate];
[yourSprite runAction:repeatAction];
```

You will want to look at the docs for textureWithRect:inTexture:  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/textureWithRect:inTexture:)  for more information. Remember it is a range of 0 to 1.

I hope that answers your question or at least gets you started in the right direction.